# monad-controlのMonadTransControlとMonadBaseControlについて

Tags: haskell

monad-controlパッケージにはMonadTransControlとMonadBaseControlがありますが、どのような使い分けをするのが正しいのでしょうか？
http://maoe.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20111207/1323185162
には

> 簡単に解説すると、MonadTransControlクラスのliftWith :: Monad m => (Run t -> m a) ->
>   t m aはモナドスタックt m aを一つpopした型m
>   aを弄れるようにする役割を持ち、MonadBaseControlのliftBaseWith :: (RunInBase m b -> b
>   a) -> m aは、スタックの最下部までpopしたベースモナドの型b aを弄れるようにする役割を持っています。

とかいてありますが、どちらも一番下まで持ち上げなければなりませんでした。
MonadTransControlはMonadBaseControlを定義するための補助なのでしょうか？

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.Base
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Name  = String
type Value = String
type Env   = Map.Map Name Value
-- EvalRの内部
newtype EvalE m a = EvalE {runEvalE :: ExceptT String m a}
  deriving (Functor
          , Applicative
          , Monad
          , MonadError String
          , MonadBase base
          )
instance MonadTrans EvalE where
  lift = EvalE . lift

instance MonadTransControl EvalE where
  type StT EvalE a = StT (ExceptT String) a
  liftWith = defaultLiftWith EvalE runEvalE
  restoreT = defaultRestoreT EvalE

instance (MonadBaseControl b m) => MonadBaseControl b (EvalE m) where
  type StM (EvalE m) a = ComposeSt EvalE m a
  liftBaseWith     = defaultLiftBaseWith
  restoreM         = defaultRestoreM
evalET :: (Monad (t []), MonadTransControl t) => t [] Int
evalET = return 1
evalEM :: (MonadBaseControl [] m) => m Int
evalEM = return 1

doEvalET :: EvalE [] Int -> EvalE [] Int
doEvalET t = liftWith (\run -> run t) >>= restoreT . return
doEvalEM :: EvalE [] Int -> EvalE [] Int
doEvalEM m = liftBaseWith (\run -> run m) >>= restoreM

exEvalE  :: EvalE [] Int -> IO ()
exEvalE  = print . runEvalE
exEvalET :: EvalE [] Int -> IO ()
exEvalET = print . runEvalE . doEvalET
exEvalEM :: EvalE [] Int -> IO ()
exEvalEM = print . runEvalE . doEvalEM

newtype EvalR m a = EvalR {runEvalR :: ReaderT Env (EvalE m) a}
  deriving (Functor
          , Applicative
          , Monad
          , MonadError String
          , MonadReader Env
          , MonadBase base
          )
instance MonadTrans EvalR where
  lift = EvalR . lift . lift

-- 全部持ち上げないとだめだった
-- 本当は1つだけ持ち上げてEvalEにしかかった
instance MonadTransControl EvalR where
  type StT EvalR a = StT EvalE (StT (ReaderT Env) a)
  liftWith f = EvalR $ liftWith $ \runReader ->
                          liftWith $ \runEval ->
                            f $ runEval . runReader . runEvalR
  restoreT = EvalR . restoreT . restoreT

instance (MonadBaseControl b m) => MonadBaseControl b (EvalR m) where
    type StM (EvalR m) a = ComposeSt EvalR m a
    liftBaseWith     = defaultLiftBaseWith
    restoreM         = defaultRestoreM

env :: Env
env = Map.fromList [("0", "zero"), ("1", "one")]

doEvalRT :: EvalR [] Int -> EvalR [] Int
doEvalRT t = do
    x <- liftWith $ \r ->
      r t
    restoreT $ return x
doEvalRM :: EvalR [] Int -> EvalR [] Int
doEvalRM m = liftBaseWith (\run -> run m) >>= restoreM

exEvalR  :: EvalR [] Int -> IO ()
exEvalR  = print . runEvalE . (flip runReaderT env) . runEvalR
exEvalRT :: EvalR [] Int -> IO ()
exEvalRT = print . runEvalE . (flip runReaderT env) . runEvalR . doEvalRT
exEvalRM :: EvalR [] Int -> IO ()
exEvalRM = print . runEvalE . (flip runReaderT env) . runEvalR . doEvalRM
```

それとも型がt m aとm aで型が違うのでうまく使い分けるのでしょうか？

```
maybeTIO :: (Monad (t IO), MonadTransControl t) => t IO Int
maybeTIO = lift     (putStrLn "testMaybeT") >> return 1
maybeMIO :: (MonadBaseControl IO m) => m Int
maybeMIO = liftBase (putStrLn "testMaybeT") >> return 1

twiceIO :: IO a -> IO a
twiceIO action = action >> action

testLiftWith     :: MaybeT IO Int -> MaybeT IO Int
testLiftWith     f = liftWith     (\run -> twiceIO (run f)) >>= restoreT . return
testLiftBaseWith :: MaybeT IO Int -> MaybeT IO Int
testLiftBaseWith f = liftBaseWith (\run -> twiceIO (run f)) >>= restoreM
testControl      :: MaybeT IO Int -> MaybeT IO Int
testControl      f = control (\run -> twiceIO (run maybeTIO))
```

Answer (score 2):

提示された例では、`MaybeT IO`という二階層のモナドスタックが使用されているため、`MonadTransControl`を使っても`MonadBaseControl`を使っても持ち上げられ方は変わりませんが、三階層以上のスタックを使うと違いが明確になります。

以下の例では、`StateT Int (MaybeT IO)`という三階層のスタックを使っています。この場合、`MonadBaseControl`を使用した`testLiftBaseWith2`は自動的に二階層持ち上げてくれるので、`testLiftBaseWith`のコードがそのまま使えます。一方、`MonadTransControl`を使用した`testLiftWith2`では、一つの`liftWith`が一階層しか持ち上げないため、明示的に二回持ち上げる必要があります。

```
testLiftWith2 :: StateT Int (MaybeT IO) Int -> StateT Int (MaybeT IO) Int
testLiftWith2 f = liftWith (\runState -> liftWith (\runMaybe -> twiceIO (runMaybe (runState f))) >>= restoreT . return) >>= restoreT . return

testLiftBaseWith2 :: StateT Int (MaybeT IO) Int -> StateT Int (MaybeT IO) Int
testLiftBaseWith2 f = liftBaseWith (\run -> twiceIO (run f)) >>= restoreM
```

`MonadTrans`の`lift`が一階層しか持ち上げないのに対して、`MonadIO`の`liftIO`が最下層の`IO`を何階層でも持ち上げられるのと同様に考えれば良いと思います（`MonadBase`は`MonadIO`をSTモナドにも適用できるように一般化したものです）。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
EvalRのMonadTransControlの定義について知りたかったのですが、
回答を見て気付きました。
自分で複数階層重ねた定義というのはそれで1つとみなすのですね。